# Use pandas for data grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv formatted like:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
data1,data2,data3
data1,data2,data3
```

And I was able to convert it to json in this format:

```
[
  {
    "Column1": "data1",
    "Column2": "data2",
    "Column3": "data3",
  },
  {
    "Column1": "data1",
    "Column2": "data2",
    "Column3": "data3",
  },
]
```

with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_csv(r'ReactStepsSubsteps.csv', encoding='windows-1254')

newList = []
for index, item in df.iterrows():
    newDict = {}
    for key in item.keys():
        newDict[key] = item[key]

    newList.append(newDict)

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(newList, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

Is there a way to do this exclusively with helper functions from pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pandas documentation for [to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) list several orientations the output data can have.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': {0: 'data1', 1: 'data1'},
 'Column2': {0: 'data2', 1: 'data2'},
 'Column3': {0: 'data3', 1: 'data3'}})

df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "Column1":"data1",
        "Column2":"data2",
        "Column3":"data3"
    },
    {
        "Column1":"data1",
        "Column2":"data2",
        "Column3":"data3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
newList = df.to_json(orient="records")
```